# Setting height of div + scroll to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, height

I'm trying to get a page to scroll to the bottom automatically - easiest thing in the world, right? Well not so much. We've got a SPA (using Kendo UI) for a very simple discussion forum. Part of the JS for that page includes setting the height of our content div, which I've discovered is preventing the standard scrollTop functionality from working.

Here's the page: 
[image: discussion forum page]

The header is static, and the footer is sticky at the bottom of the page. You'll notice the scrollbar doesn't go behind the add comment section, which is part of the reason we're setting the height.

Setting the height:

```
$('.content-area').height($(window).height() - ($('header nav').height() + $('.disc-add-comment-cont').height()));
```

.content-area is everything on the page, excluding the header and the nav. header nav is the static header, and .disc-add-comment-cont is the add comment footer.

The code I'm using for the bottom scroll is about as vanilla as it comes:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");
```

I've also tried:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(window).height() - ($('header nav').height() + $('.disc-add-comment-cont').height()) }, "slow");
```

to account for the first height calc, but no luck.

I need the scroll to bottom functionality to work, even with our existing height calculation. I would have a pretty hard time posting a workable example, but I'm 100% certain it's our height calculation. Leave it in the code, scroll doesn't work. Comment it out, scroll works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scroll that you have there is on the `.content-area` element, and not on `html` or `body`, so you should scroll that element:

```
$(".content-area").animate({scrollTop: $('.content-area').prop("scrollHeight")}, "slow");
```

Comment: Oh, of course! Can't believe I missed that - although I did try to target other divs inside .content-area. Thanks!